# WP Bakery and Astra Pro CSS/JavaScript layout issue

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wpbakery, wordpress-theme-astra

i have issue with my Astra + WP Bakery Visual Conposer. I can't understand if this is a css or Jquery (or both issue)

After first page loading everything is fine, then as I scroll, main layout container go beyond the right edge on mobile (and desktop too).

[image]

[image]

I have tried to add css rules and contacting WP Bakery and Astra Pro support and both of them send me to the other support team!

If I try to use WP bakery on the default theme this doesn't happen.

Comment: It will be helpful if we can access the page or get the minimum code to replicate the issue. Without any code to check and debug, we can not help much. Please hit and try some CSS which may fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This will fix the issue:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
}
```